# Can't invoke dynamic method from generic class

Tags: .net, generics

I'm trying to work with two contexts in a generic repository and I should invoke the static method `GetObjectContext()` with dynamic type like `ObjectContextManager<DynamicType>.GetObjectContext()`.

```
private DataContext GetDataContext()
    {
        Type type = GetContainerType();
        Type paoloGenericClassType = typeof(ObjectContextManager<>).MakeGenericType(type);

        MethodInfo method = paoloGenericClassType.GetMethod("GetObjectContext", BindingFlags.Static);
        return method.Invoke(null, BindingFlags.Static, null, null, null) as DataContext;
    }
```

I'm try different variants, but it doesn't work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is just with your binding flags. Try `BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public`, assuming it's a public method.

If that doesn't work, please tell us what actually happens, rather than just saying it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. I try this variant
 private DataContext GetDataContext()
        {
            Type type = GetContainerType();
            Type paoloGenericClassType = typeof(ObjectContextManager<>).MakeGenericType(type);
            return paoloGenericClassType.InvokeMember("GetObjectContext",
                  BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, new object[] { }) as DataContext;
        }
But I have the same error.

Comment: @Alex: Well your type initializer is throwing an exception, apparently. I suggest you put a break point on it and see what's going on in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this article on how to invoke generic methods via reflection.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/10/10/invoking-generic-methods-with-reflection.aspx

http://avantprime.com/articles/view-article/16/invoke-a-generic-method-with-parameters-using-reflection

DaTribe